# Python algorithms nth prime number

Tags: python, algorithm

Question:
    Given the prime number n, output the number of prime numbers

My code:

```
    def kthPrime(self, n):
            if n>10 and n%10 not in [1,3,7,9]:
                return 0
            if n == 2:
                return 1
            queue = []
            num = 2
            while num <= n:
                if n%num == 0 and num != n:
                    return 0
                if num>10 and num%10 not in [1,3,7,9]:
                    num += 1 
                    continue
                for i in range(2,num/2+1):
                    if num%i == 0:
                        num += 1 
                        break
                else:    
                    queue.append(num)
                    num += 1
            seq = queue.index(n) + 1
            return seq
```

Error:
    Your code ran too much time than we expected. Check your time complexity. Time limit exceeded usually caused by infinite loop if your time complexity is the best.

My Question: how to improve it

Comment: This would be more appropriate on [codereview.se] if it's on topic there based on their posting guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  Given the quantity of efficient prime-finding algorithms available on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the net, you should have a much more specific question than the one you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

as user @Prune said , please read the guide first.
I'm not going to tell you how to improve your function , but I'm just gonna give you a faster way to see whether a number is prime or not and hopefully you will understand how to use the function that I'm gonna give you to improve your own function.
The source code :

```
class numChecker:
    def is_prime(self,n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n < 2:
        return False

    self.square_root = int(n ** (1/2))

    for divisor in range(3, self.square_root + 1, +2):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True
```